# Nuxt3 custom routing breaks vue-router and <nuxt-link> instances

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router, nuxtjs3

I have a Nuxt3 application that is currently composed of pages essentially in the following format:

```
pages/
|-- index.vue
|-- test-directory/
|   |-- [slug].vue
|   |-- test.vue
|   |-- index.vue
```

I need the test.vue file to take precedence over the slug pages, so I looked into [custom routing](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing#adding-custom-routes). I created an app/router.options.ts file, which looks like this:

```js
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema';

export default <RouterConfig> {
  routes: _routes => [
    // home
    {
      name: 'home',
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('~/pages/index.vue').then(r => r.default || r),
    },

    {
      name: 'test-directory',
      path: '/test-directory',
      component: () => import('~/pages/test-directory/index.vue'),
    },
    {
      name: 'test-directory-test',
      path: '/test-directory/test',
      component: () => import('~/pages/test-directory/test.vue'),
    },
    {
      name: 'test-directory-slug',
      path: '/test-directory/:slug',
      component: () => import('~/pages/test-directory/[slug].vue'),
    },
  ],
};
```

After saving the file and restarting the server, all of the pages break and I get the error: `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/@vite/client"`. The browser console shows an error `[nuxt] error caught during app initialization Error: No match for {"name":"index","params":{}}`. It also appears like all of the instances of `<nuxt-link>` that are used throughout are broken and don't render to the DOM.

Is there something I'm missing with setting up custom routing?

**EDIT:**
I tried another method using the `pages:extend` hook in the Nuxt.config.

```js
  hooks: {
    'pages:extend': (pages) => {
      pages.push({
        name: 'test-directory-test',
        path: '/test-directory/test',
        file: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/test-directory/test.vue'),
      });
    },
  },
```

This is much closer, in that the `<nuxt-link` elements render correctly. If I click a link to that page however, it matches with the slug file, and if I refresh the page it correctly renders the Test.vue file. I'm not entirely sure how to fix it from here though.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered that the nuxt-link I was using was still sending the user to the named slug route. Ended up creating the app/router.options.ts file, then changing those nuxt-link props and everything works properly!